Issue faced in importing data from desktop
Data was placed on desktop
carData=read.csv('mtcars.csv') #this I wrote in code chunk
console ::
carData=read.csv('mtcars.csv')
Warning: cannot open file 'mtcars.csv': No such file or directoryError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
I am new in this field, expecting layman language.

Your current working directory (you can check you current working directory usind getwd()) is probably not your Desktop, which is why R can't find the datafile.
It might be easiest for you to supply the entire path to the file. On Windows this could be 'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop'.
You can also navigate to the correct working directory usind setwd('path').
To check all availyble files and folders in you current wd you can use dir().
Hope this helps!

did yo mean getwd()?

Sure. Just mistyped. Thanks for the correction!
